# Node, MongoClient and Mongodb, infinite loop not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have some code which has been put together with a little understanding. I am building my knowledge as i go along. I am trying to assign some random data to a variable which works fine and then insert that in to the database by using an infinite loop and a sleep function (I have heard sleep isnt the best way but the code doesnt have to be perfect). The data is inserted once and then the variable is reassigned but it doesnt get inserted in to the database.

```
function main() {      
//import mongodb and assign it to variable mongodb
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
//use mongodb variable to assign the Mongo Client to te vaariable
MongoClient
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
//Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
if (err) {
  while (true) {
    console.log('Assign var');
    //Create an entry for db
    var tempvalue = {
      'time': Date.now(),
      'type': 'Temperature',
      'location': 1,
      'value': getRandomInt(25, 28)
    };
    console.log(tempvalue);
    sensorcollection.insert({
      'time': Date.now(),
      'type': 'Temperature',
      'location': 1,
      'value': getRandomInt(25, 28)
      },
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('The documents inserted with "_id" are:', result);
        }
      });
    //console.log('inserted');
    sleepFor(10000);

    //console.log('where am i');
  }
}
});
}

main();
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you use if(err) to execute your code, which means that you only insert you docs when the connection to the DB failed.
- Second you use sensorcollection variable which don't seems to exists, you should ask MongoDB to fetch the collection for you.
- Third you use sleepFor which is not a node.js function, use setTimeout instead.

You should really look at node.js model to understand what's wrong.

Try this instead:

```
function main() {      
    //import mongodb and assign it to variable mongodb
    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    //use mongodb variable to assign the Mongo Client to te vaariable
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    //Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
    // Use connect method to connect to the Server
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (!err) {
            //you need to fetch the MongoDB collection object
            db.collection('sensorcollection', function(err, col) {
                if(err)
                    return console.error('Error while fetching collection', err)

                //void function() {}() declare a function add call it, you can do the same with main()
                void function addStat() {
                    var tempvalue = {
                        'time': Date.now(),
                        'type': 'Temperature',
                        'location': 1,
                        'value': getRandomInt(25, 28)
                    };

                    col.insert(tempvalue, function(err, result) {
                        if(err)
                            console.log(err)
                        else {
                            console.log('The documents inserted with "_id" are:', result);
                            setTimeout(addStat, 10000) //wait 10000 before inserting
                        }
                    })
                }()
            })
        }
        else {
            console.error('MongoDB error', err)
        }
    });
}

main();
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your feedback, when moving the code over i missed off the else after the if (err). I also had a sleep function but the setTimeout seems to of fixed the issue i was having because  i thought i could put an infinte lopp around it all but you just used the setTimeout to call a function changing the variable and inserting again.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line after connect is

```
if (err)
```

So only if your connection fails, you try to insert?
Shouldn't it be something like

```
if (!err)
```